# importing images in different folde in python

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import GoPro_large dataset in python. I downloaded the dataset from google drive however, each image is taken in blurred and sharp formats and each scene is in a different folder. (please refer to the screenshots). How can I import every sharp image from all the scenes in Python?
[image][image][image]

I expect the code to go through every root folder (eg,GOPR0884*_11_XX), go inside the sharp folder for each and import all the sharp images in that folder.*

Comment: start with the `glob` module.

Answer (score 0):

This is working :

```
from os import listdir, getcwd
from os.path import isdir, join, splitext
from PIL import Image

pictures=[]

mypath=getcwd()
for directory in listdir(mypath) : #all files/directory in pwd

    dir=join(mypath,directory)
    if(isdir(dir) and "sharp" in listdir(dir)): #Should be a dir and contain "sharp" dir

        sharpdir=join(dir,"sharp")
        for file in listdir(sharpdir) : #all the picture in sharp/

            picture=join(sharpdir,file)
            if(splitext(picture)[1]==".png") : #Should be a .png
                pictures.append(Image.open(picture))
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: nice method, but is the `glob` module better suited ?

Comment: I don't know, probably

Answer (score 0):

As there is no code to correct, the best offer is a boiler plate example to the `glob` module which will perform the task required.

The glob module in Python is used to find files that match a specific pattern.

two functions of use would be:

- `glob()`: This function returns a list of all the files that match the specified pattern.
- `iglob()`: This function is similar to glob(), but it is used to iterate over the files that match the specified pattern.

Here is an example of `glob()`:

```py
import glob

# Find all the files in the current directory that end with .py
files = glob.glob("*.py")

# Print the names of the files
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

...without details (or code), this is the best that can be offered.